# RoomDatabase not rebuilding after version change

Tags: android, android-room, android-database

I'm using the Android RoomDatabase.
Upon application start I trigger the database to initialize itself simply by calling `getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();`. I'm then waiting for the onOpen callback of the DatabaseBuilder.

As soon as I add another field to one of my entities this doesn't seem to work anymore. onOpen just isn't called.
So I changed the version number from 1 to 2 in order to force the database to rebuild itself.

```
@Database(entities = {Preference.class}, version = 2)
```

But that worked neither. Neither onCreate or onOpen were called.

The only thing that worked for me is to give the DatabaseBuilder a new databasename. But that just doesn't seem right.

So my question is:
Why isn't onCreate and therefore onOpen called after I change the version number of my Database?

Comment: share your logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using the `getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase()` methods? When you instantiate the database you should be using the `Room.databaseBuilder()` method. This will instantiate the database for you and then you can use it throughout your application without ever having to deal with writable/readable databases as Room is handling that part for you. (Ideally, you'd want to follow the singleton pattern for this so you only ever instantiate the database once.)

You can find further documentation on this here:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

Hope that helps.

**Update**

So based on the feedback you gave to this I did some further testing into this. You can get the database to open or create by running `.isOpen()` on your writable database. My assumption at this point is that the database isn't actually opened or created until it is expressly needed. I'm assuming that when you call `getWritableDatabase()` it isn't actually opening the database at all just returning an object that can be opened and isn't considered closed. Hence why when you run `isOpen()` it returns true and opens the database. I hope that is a more helpful answer for you.

**Note on Migration**

When you update the database to a new version number you need to have a valid migration class to update the database from and to the correct version. Documentation on this can be found here:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions.html

Alternatively, for development you can use the function `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` on your Room Database Builder to use a destructive migration. This will simply destroy your pre-existing database and recreate it. **Warning: All data in the database will be lost using this method.**

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I'm using the Room as it's intended to be used. I'm only calling the getWritableDatabase once in my MainActivity onCreate. I do this so the database "thinks" it's needed and initializes itself and the callback "onOpen" of my builder is called.

Until the onOpen is called the user sees a progress bar. So when that as soon as the user interacts with the app I can make sure the database is already ready.

Comment: Would it not be worthwhile just using a callback instead? Like there's the  RoomDatabase.Callback class with two methods `onOpen` and `onCreate`. You just create it as an anonymous class and then add it to the builder using the `addCallback(RoomDatabase.Callback)` method.

This should do exactly what I think you are wanting it to do?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. The thing is the database is not automatically opened on app start, but only on the first access. Therefore I "fake" the first access by calling `getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase()` to give the database a little push to do its thing.

Comment: Out of curiosity does it work if you run a query against the database instead of using the `getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase()` method?

Comment: Thanks! You kinda pushed me in the right direction. By executing a query I got a concrete exception which stated that I'm missing a migration from 1 to 2. For now I just added `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` which works just fine.

Would you like to add that to your answer? Than I'd except your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Certainly, and thanks. Glad I could help with this in some capacity.